# Scalatra - how do we do an internal redirect / forward of request

Tags: redirect, forward, scalatra

I want to call another internal url from my scalatra 'controller'. I can't do a simple redirect, as there's some security settings that mean a user has access only to the first url.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
get("/foo") {
  servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/bar").forward(request, response)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The get() method is defined as (similar to POST, et al):

```
def get(transformers : org.scalatra.RouteTransformer*)(action : => scala.Any) : org.scalatra.Route
```

Depends on what you mean by internal redirect, I presume you just want to execute another route's action. You have a few options of what you can do.  This seems to be working for me:

```
val canonicalEndpoint = get("/first/route") {
  //do things in here    
}
```

Then you could subsequently do:

```
get("/second/route")( canonicalEndpoint.action )
```

And I think you would get your desired response.

I like saving the whole Route response of the get() as you may also want to use that with scalatra's url() function in routing.